# Call external url with parameter in PHP

Tags: php, url, curl

I have been working to call external url from PHP (on submit) with parameter. I have looked different option (`curl`, `file_get_contents` etc), but nothing seems to working.

This is how final url should look like:

```
http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user=temp&memory_mb=1024&num_cpus=1&eth0_ip=172.XX.XX.XXX&eth1_ip=192.XX.XX.XX
```

And with parameter it looks this way:

```
http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user=$login&memory_mb=$memory&num_cpus=$cpu&eth0_ip=$ip_172&eth1_ip=$ip_192";
```

Comment: Try Guzzle https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Your PHP code is wrong! You did not escaped the variables you used! Show us the code where you generate the URL.

Comment: How would that help with his issue? @JaredChu

Answer (score 1):

You did not escaped the variables you used while creating the URL. If you placed variables in a string, you need to tell, what a variable is and what the string is.

For example, you could use bracers around the varibales:

```
$url = "http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user={$login}&memory_mb={$memory}&num_cpus={$cpu}&eth0_ip={$ip_172}&eth1_ip={$ip_192}";
```

Or exclude them from the string:

```
$url = "http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user=" . $login . "&memory_mb=" . $memory . "&num_cpus=" . $cpu . "&eth0_ip=" . $ip_172 . "&eth1_ip=" . $ip_192;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct quotation characters `"` instead of `'` around the string or you might concat the parameters/strings using a `.`

A possible solution is:

```
$url = 'http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user='.$login.'&memory_mb='.$memory.'&num_cpus='.$cpu.'&eth0_ip='.$ip_172.'&eth1_ip='.$ip_192;
```

Comment: As you see in his example, he used `"` (end of the line).

Comment: If there is the correct quotation `"`, the code given in the question should work. Because it's not mandatory to use curly braces around simple variables. This is only required for arrays or objects, which is not the case here.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 0):

Build your url as a string then use `file_get_contents()`

```
$login = "userName";
$memory = "memoryValue";
$cpu = "cpuValue";
$ip = "127_0_100_"; 

$url = "http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user=" . $login . "&memory_mb=" . $memory . "&num_cpus=" . $cpu . "&eth0_ip=" . $ip . "_172&eth1_ip=" . $ip . "_192";

$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: You messed up the ip variables a bit. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr following the original string it has the IP separated by `_` instead of the traditional `.` -- I was trying to stay as true to the URL string example as I could. :)

Comment: I don't know where you looked, but see his example url. It's dot annotated, just the variable names are `$ip_172` and `$ip_192`.

Answer (score -1):

Build your url with all define param as a string then use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [curl()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
$url = "http://XXXXX:8080/job/Clone_CentOS_VM/buildWithParameters?token=smlvyKf6tS&vm_user=".$login."&memory_mb=".$memory."&num_cpus=".$cpu."&eth0_ip=".$ip_172."&eth1_ip=".$ip_192;
```

1. with ***[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)*** :

   file_get_contents($url);
2. with ***[curl()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)***

   ```
           $request_headers[] =  'Content-Type:application/json';
           if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
               die('cURL is not installed. Install and try again.');
           }
           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
           $result = curl_exec($ch);
   ```